# Two raters’ inter-reader reliability versus two-classifier classification accuracy

Tags: classification, agreement-statistics

30 patients have a CT and a pseudo-CT scan image, I want to get them scored for the presence of a disease to know if the pseudo-CT has the same diagnostic performance as CT.
I give these two sets (30 CT and 30 pseudo-CT) to two radiologists to score them for the presence of disease using an ordinal score of 0-3.

What would be the best measure for this? Should I see that as an inter-reader reliability and go for Cohen’s kappa? Or should I see that as classifier accuracy evaluation and go for its metrics?

Answer (score 1):

Inter-rater, inter-coder and classifier accuracy are the same thing. But since they stem from different fields, the handbooks recommend different metrics. All metrics may be applied to all of them, however.

The metric that would be most useful in your case is Krippendorff's alpha for ordinal variables (since a 1-3 disagreement would be worse than a 2-3 disagreement). Most other coefficients for interrater agreement (Cohen's Kappa, Scott's Pi, Holsti...) don't distinguish between the types and gravity of errors.

Quite inapplicable would be the metrics used for dichotomous classification accuracy. Since you have four categories, you would have to recode the ratings and lose information.

Since you have few cases and only 2 coders, you could also just look at a cross-tabulation of ratings to identify eventual systematic biases (e.g. when radiologist 1 sometimes gives lower scores than radiologist 2 but never higher ones). This might also be interesting.

Comment: One display for such data is exemplified in Section 6 of https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200314